# How to esttab the weakiv test result?

Tags: stata

I want to `esttab` the `weakiv` result in table
But I try many ways but cannot show the result in Stata.
What's the problem?

Here is sample code.

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo:ivreg2 price (displacement=mpg)

weakiv

estadd scalar AR=e(ar_chi2),replace
estadd scalar Wald=e(wald_chi2),replace

esttab,scalar(AR Wald)
```

But the result do not show the `AR` and `Wald` result

```
----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
displacement        21.33***
                   (4.55)   

_cons              1957.4*  
                   (2.01)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
AR                          
Wald                        
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

My exception is I can show the AR and Wald result in the regression part.